# Xcode4: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4

I am getting this Exception in xcode4 with the iphone simulator:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'
```

It seems to be caused if you return no objects(return 0) back in the cellForRowAtIndex method.  But I have mine set to return the cell.

Can anyone see what may be causing this error?  Here is a bunch of screenshots:

Controller Configuration:
[image: My Controller configuration]

Prototype cell
[image: prototype cell 1]

attentionCell:
[image]

Storyboards:
[image: Full view of the storyboards]

Full Error:

```
**Assertion failure in -[UITableView 
_createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:],           
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
2012-07-30 14:34:16.660 Simple Storyboard[263:f803] Terminating app due 
to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from 
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'**
```

Here is the code:

```
#import "LWWBidTaskListController.h"

@interface LWWBidTaskListController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *tasks;

@end

@implementation LWWBidTaskListController

@synthesize tasks;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.tasks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Walk the dog", @"URGENT:Buy milk", @"Clean     hidden lair", @"Invent miniature dolphins", @"Find new henchmen", @"Get revenge on do-gooder heroes", @"URGENT: Fold laundry", @"Hold entire hold hostage", @"Manicure", nil];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this     view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
self.tasks = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
//return 0;
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
//return 0;
return [tasks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath//populates each cell
{
//static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


NSString *identifier = nil;
NSString *task = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSRange urgentRange = [task rangeOfString:@"URGENT"];
if (urgentRange.location == NSNotFound)
{
    identifier = @"plainCell";
}
else 
{
    identifier = @"attentionCell";
}
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

// Configure the cell...

UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
cellLabel.text = task;

return cell;
}
```

What does that error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you never create a cell. If you have never allocated and initialized a cell then there are none to dequeue.
before the // Configure the cell.. line you need to check if a reusable cell was dequeued and if not, create one like so:

```
if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  // Configure common elements here

}

  // Now go on to configure specific elements for this row
```

As you are using storyboard, perhaps you have not set up the prototype cell attributes correctly. The identifiers must match those in your method above.

See this pic for where you find the prototype cell attributes [Prototype cell setup](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Prototype-cell.png). it is from this tutorial that may help you as well [Ray Wenderlich and Storyboards](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

Comment: If the OP is using a storyboard, he might be using prototype cells, in which case `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always return something if you're passing a identifier you've set up in the storyboard.

Comment: That is news to me. I haven't used Storyboards.

Comment: Yes that is correct Jesse I have two different prototype cells which are in that if else loop of(attentionCell and plainCell).

Comment: So yes the cell is created already Dean.  Thanks..I am not sure what else it could be...

Comment: @Chi at least go give this answer a try. There's no other reason the cell would be nil for.

Comment: After a quick read of the storyboard docs, my first thought is did you set up your prototype cells properly in the attributes inspector?

Comment: Thanks Dean for pointing that out, I didn't have the tag set to 1 that was missing. That is fixed now, but still getting the same error.  I'm searching some more..I have added some screenshots too..

Comment: I don't see where you will set tag for the label. I don't think that is going to work when you get there. Of course, one thing at a time as you have to produce a valid cell before you can set any properties. I think you do not need the cell viewWithTag: call. You are using a standard cell style so just use cell.textLabel.text = task.

Comment: Thanks Dean.  The tag lets us find the label from within our code.  So when I set the tag to 1 it knows which cell/s I am referring to.

Comment: I see that but you actually have reference to the cell already, regardless of the tag. I am not sure the method, as I see it in your post will give the proper reference to the uiLabel. I may be wrong as I don't have all the info. Did you manage to return a valid cell and stop the error?

Comment: actually now, I looked at your screen shots and see that you have the uiLabel available to the inspector. I presume that is where you set the tag. In that case the method will work as intended. I don't believe it is necessary, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your second prototype cell has to be part of your tableView in the story board, right now its a part of same scene only - probably thats why you're getting nil.

Anyway try to:

```
NSLog(@"current cell: %@ -> %@", identifier, cell);
```

and check what `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is returning.

---

Just drag and drop `attentionCell` into table view 
[image: ..]

Comment: Yes, in other words, add a second prototype cell for the other reuse identifier.

Comment: Yes, looking at the screen shot I see the second prototype cell needs to be moved to the tableview. You should be able to drag it over. The first time you need to produce a "attention" cell. It will certainly fail.

Comment: Hmm..thanks Lupatus.  It is coming back null...so it must be my configuration then I suppose?

2012-07-30 19:20:30.302 Simple Storyboard[314:f803] current cell: plainCell -> <UITableViewCell: 0x68648e0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6864600>>
2012-07-30 19:20:30.305 Simple Storyboard[314:f803] current cell: attentionCell -> (null)

Comment: add a second prototype cell? I have two prototype cells.  You mean add another one to make it three?  Can you explain on that Jesse?